# Can't use :: Integral

Tags: haskell, integral

I don't understand why I can't do this

`fromIntegral (4 :: Integral) :: Double`

*fromIntegral* function has such prototype:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

I think that it should be 4.0 (Double) as result.
But when I try this - an error happends:

```
<interactive>:72:20: error:
    * Expecting one more argument to `Integral'
      Expected a type, but `Integral' has kind `* -> Constraint'
    * In an expression type signature: Integral
      In the first argument of `fromIntegral', namely `(4 :: Integral)'
      In the expression: fromIntegral (4 :: Integral) :: Double
```

Comment: `Integral` is not a type, but a type class (~ a set of types, not just a single one). Instead, `Int`, `Integer`, `Double` are types.

Comment: The `:kind`: of `Integral :: Type -> Constraint` versus `Integer :: Type`.

Comment: No annotation is necessary anyway. `fromIntegral` expects an argument of type `Integral a => a`, so that's the type that will be inferred for `4`, even if it's "actual" type is the more general `Num a => a`.